# Retorno de um Checkbox ao Javascript

Tags: checkbox

Preciso de uma ajuda, olhei os posts anteriores ao um assunto parecido, mas não encontrei um exemplo como o meu, se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Tenho uma View de Edição que já traz o valor cadastrado de um checkbox.

```
<div class="col-md-1 ">
     Aprovado
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Aprovado, new {Attributes = new { @class = 
     "form-control" ,  @style = "font-size:12px;", @id = "aprovado", 
     @name="aprovado"} })
</div>
```

Tenho um Botão finalizar que envia os dados para gravação, só que o checkbox não funciona, tentei depurar mas apresenta como indefinido.

```
    $("#finalizar").click(function () {

        alert($("#aprovado").val());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não recebe nada porque o checkbox não possui o atributo `value`, apenas class, name, id e style.

Se deseja receber o valor "aprovado", inclua o atributo `@value = "aprovado"` no elemento. Talvez você deva ter pensado que o `@name="aprovado"` é o que seria enviado no formulário, mas não. O que são enviados são os values dos elementos, não os names.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de você checar se o checkbox está checado:

```
$('#aprovado').prop('checked');
```